# TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having python script which contains fetching data from MySql DB and then parse that data

below is the way I fetch data from MY SQL db

```
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host = "192.168.1.50", user = "root", 
password = "root", db = "mydb", port = 32768)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from licenses")
data = cursor.fetchall()
```

Below is small chunk of output

```
print(data)

((1,
  'MS SQl',
  'eaf5e1b212e0ad3c4a6172a9e9fd30145dd2d9bf070cc2568fdef384ab63254c',
  datetime.date(2017, 2, 23),
  Decimal('30000.00'),
  '21022018',
  2,
  '',
  1,
  None,
  datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 21, 9, 51, 22),
  datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 21, 11, 26, 17),
  None,
  'Hudson Bay',
  'hudson.bay@ifficeemailid.com',
  None,
  None,
  datetime.date(2018, 2, 24),
  '21022018',
  datetime.date(2018, 2, 25),
  1,
  1,
  0,
  None),
 (2,
  'Palo Alto',
  'eaf5e1b212e0',
  datetime.date(2017, 2, 2),
  Decimal('50000.00'),
  '',
  2,
  '',
  1,
  None,
  datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 21, 10, 5, 16),
  datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 12, 21, 51),
  None,
  'John Snow',
  'john.snow@officeemailid.com',
  None,
  None,
  datetime.date(2018, 2, 22),
  'eaf5e1b212e0',
  datetime.date(2018, 2, 22),
  1,
  1,
  0,
  None))
```

When I tried to get data from row 17 I can get

```
for row in data:
    print row[17]
2018-02-24
2018-02-22
```

However when I tried to add condition it wont work.

```
for row in data:
    if '2018-02-24' in row[17]:
        print('found')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-a5803fbf5283> in <module>()
      1 for row in data:
----> 2     if '2018-02-28' in row[17]:
      3         print(yes)
      4 

TypeError: argument of type 'datetime.date' is not iterable
```

My Final Objective is getting date from code like = `today = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`
On above code '2018-02-24' I have hardcoaded, in actual scenario I and getting that fro 'today' variable
and check if that date is available in 'row 17'

but getting error, any way to solve this?

Comment: What are you expecting `'2018-02-28' in row[17]` to do if `row[17]` is a `datetime.date` object?

Comment: If you're trying to check whether the date is 2018-02-28, you do that with `==`, not `in` (of course you'll have to convert one or the other so they have the same type, but that's pretty simple).

Comment: @VikasDamodar That's not true. You can use `in` for substring tests in `str` and `bytes` and similar types, for membership tests in all kinds of sequences besides lists and non-sequence containers like sets, and for key checking in dicts and other mappings. Almost anywhere `x in y` makes sense, it's legal. The problem here is that `y` seems to be a date, and `x in y` doesn't make sense for finding a string in a date.

Comment: Btw, your code prints the 18th *column*, not row.

Comment: @abarnert, yes `row[17]` is `datetime.date` object. The answer suggested by you earlier and @RaoSaheb in below answer I tried it with `==` and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: Also, the code you claim throws the error is not what is shown in the error itself.

Comment: "I tried it with `==` and it doesn't return anything" can't be true. An `==` always gives you True or False; there's no way it can not give you anything. You'll have to show us the relevant code if you want any help with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in` to search for the date in the entire column, not an individual object:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
if today in (row[17] for row in data):
    print('found')
```

There is no need to convert to string if you are comparing date objects. If you have `datetime` instead of `date` in the column, you need to do one extra transformation:

```
today = datetime.date.today()
if today in (row[17].date() for row in data):
    print('found')
```

The explicit generator can be replaced by either `map(itemgetter(17), data)` or `map(datetime.date, map(itemgetter(17), data))`. The latter is only necessary if you have a `datetime`, which the error shows you don't:

```
from operator import itemgetter

today = datetime.date.today()
if today in map(itemgetter(17), data):
    print('found')
```

Notice that none of these versions has an explicit loop. Since generators are iterable, `in` will do a similar linear search to your original `for` loop, but faster. The only real difference, aside from speed, is that these examples will stop looking as soon as a match is found, but your loop does not. You could achieve the same result by putting a `break` statement in the `if`.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, Makes sense, coz in data row[17] is `datetime.date(2018, 3, 13)` and here today gets exactly same. First method works.

Comment: @JaydeepChaudhari. The last option is more complicated but should run a bit faster.

Answer (score -2):

Try this, hope this helps. Assuming `row[17]` is date object.

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
tdy = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

for row in data:
    if tdy == row[17]:
        print('found')
```

Comment: Missing closing quote

Comment: You want a `datetime.date` object, not a `datetime.datetime`. Otherwise, I think this is exactly what he wants (or at least ought to want).

Comment: Also, don't convert today to a string if you're not comparing it to a string.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for pointing this out. It should have been datetime.date object